# linux: vlookup using one file to another

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to print matching strings in File1 using fields of File2 (standard file). I have tried below awk command and but only first line results are being printed, instead I would like to get all fields matching from File1 strings.

```
    cat File1
    AAA,20190221,00-00,100
    AAA,20190221,01-00,110
    AAA,20190221,02-00,120
    BBB,20190221,00-00,110
    BBB,20190221,01-00,110
    BBB,20190221,02-00,110
    CCC,20190221,00-00,110
    CCC,20190221,01-00,140
    CCC,20190221,02-00,150

    cat File2
    AAA
    BBB
```

I am using below awk method,

```
    awk -F"," -f vlookup.awk File1 File2
    (cat vlookup.awk)
    FNR==NR{
    a[$1]=$4
    next}
    { if ($1 in a) {print $1"," a[$1]} else {print $1, "NA"}  }
```

I am getting output as

```
    AAA,100
    BBB,110
    NA
```

but I need to print all the values from File1, that may increase or decrease time to time.
my expected output is

```
AAA,100
AAA,110
AAA,120
BBB,110
BBB,110
BBB,110
```

Comment: Please show the expected output for your example.

Comment: my expected output is     
    AAA,100
    AAA,110
    AAA,120
    BBB,110
    BBB,110
    BBB,110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AWK script saves from `File1` the last value from column 4 for every key from column 1 into array `a` using column 1 as index. Then it prints all array keys and values that are present in `File2`.

You should change the order of the input files and create an array of keys from `File2`, then compare the lines from `File1` with this array.

`vlookup2.awk`

```
FNR==NR {
  a[$0]=1  # Set a value in array a using current line as index
  next     # Stop processing this line, do not check other rules
}
$1 in a {  # if column1 matches any index in array a
  print $1 "," $4 # the columns you want
}
```

Run

```
awk -F "," -f vlookup2.awk File2 File1
```

to get

```
AAA,100
AAA,110
AAA,120
BBB,110
BBB,110
BBB,110
```

Note: I used File2 as the first argument.

BTW: There seems to be something wrong with your AWK script, your sample files and the output. I get two lines

```
AAA,120
BBB,110
```

which are the last lines from File1 with the corresponding key in column 1. Your example output shows the first line for `AAA`.

I get a line

```
 NA
```

(with a space before `NA`) only if File2 contains an empty line after `BBB`.